# `ld: cannot find -lc` on NixOS

Tags: nixos, nix

I have the following Nix derivation:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "scipoptsuite-${version}";
  version = "4.0.0";

  src = fetchurl {
    url = "http://scip.zib.de/download/release/scipoptsuite-${version}.tgz";
    sha256 = "087535760eae3d633e2515d942a9b22e1f16332c022be8d093372bdc68e8a661";
  };

  buildInputs = [ zlib gmp readline ];
}
```

Strangely, when running `nix-build scipoptsuite.nix`, some files are compiling just fine but then I get:

```
/nix/store/x9v0yxy5iybp2m2ccqwqkvxgjy7zrw8f-binutils-2.28/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
/nix/store/x9v0yxy5iybp2m2ccqwqkvxgjy7zrw8f-binutils-2.28/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/nix/store/x9v0yxy5iybp2m2ccqwqkvxgjy7zrw8f-binutils-2.28/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
/nix/store/x9v0yxy5iybp2m2ccqwqkvxgjy7zrw8f-binutils-2.28/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

The bad command is:

```
gcc -O3 -m64 -mtune=native obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.static.opt/zimpl.o obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.static.opt/xlpglue.o obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.static.opt/zlpglue.o obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.static.opt/ratlpstore.o obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.static.opt/ratlpfwrite.o obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.static.opt/ratmpswrite.o obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.static.opt/ratmstwrite.o obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.static.opt/ratordwrite.o obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.static.opt/ratpresolve.o -Llib -lzimpl-3.3.4.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt -lgmp -lm -lz -static -o bin/zimpl-3.3.4.linux.x86_64.gnu.static.opt
```

Does anybody have an idea why this error occurs?

Comment: Is it by any chance trying to link things statically?

Comment: Did you try checking from where this is called? e.g. by adding `preBuild = "set -x"` to the `mkDerivation` arguments, to bring bash to dump all its executed commands from before the build.

Comment: Yes, in the command above the `-static` option is used. Why is this a problem?

Comment: Instead of `preBuild = "set -x"`, I had to use a `makeFlagsArray`. See the question for the command that is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Most packages in nixpkgs don't have static libraries by default.  You need to add `glibc.static` to build inputs to get static `-lc`, for example.