# Unable to use -lfl on NixOS

Tags: nixos, nix, clang

I'm new to NixOS and I'm trying to build a project which uses Flex. I get the following error if I try and build the project
`/nix/store/b10shv9yqbgps47y0n8x7l7bq8fmp1i6-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl`
How can I resolve this?
[`ld: cannot find -lc` on NixOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371050/ld-cannot-find-lc-on-nixos) shows that I need to add `glibc.static` to shell.nix's `buildInputs` but that hasn't resolved anything.

Edit:
Here is `shell.nix`

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }

with pkgs;

stdenv.mkDerivation {
    buildInputs = {
        name = "my-project";
        buildInputs = [ flex ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `-lfl` is for `libfl`, which comes from `flex` package. That is completely different from `-lc`, which is for `libc` and comes from `glibc` package. How are you building the package and what is your expression?

Comment: What do you mean by expression? `clang -o ../../output/parser.out calc.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -lm -Wall -g` is what I'm using to compile and I include `flex` in `shell.nix`. I tried adding Flex's path before `-lfl` like `$(dirname $(which flex))/../../lib` but that  didn't solve anything.

Comment: I mean the Nix expression, e.g. `shell.nix`.

Comment: I've edited in the Nix expression. It's just above boilerplate because I'm very new to Nix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
In the make file, add:

```
FLEX_PATH := $(shell dirname $(shell which flex))
LIB_PATH := $(shell readlink -f "$(FLEX_PATH)/../lib")
```

```
clang ... -L $(LIB_PATH) -lfl ...
```

Comment: This should not be necessary. You will probably need Clang from Nixpkgs if you want path resolution to work. Replace `stdenv` with `clangStdenv`.